# Visible from another transaction after update, is it a bug in MySQL MVCC?

Tags: mysql, innodb, isolation-level, rocksdb, mvcc

Here is my case:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, value INT DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (1, 10);
```

**Session A**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = 1;
  10
```

**Session B**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = 1;
  10
```

**Session A**

```
UPDATE test SET value = value + 2 WHERE id = 1;
SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = 1;
  12
COMMIT;
```

**Session B**

```
SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = 1;
  10
```

Here I get the expected result because **Session B** have an isolated copy of row `id = 1`, i.e. the commit from **Session A** is **NOT** visible here.

But when I update this row, the isolation breaks:

**Session B**

```
UPDATE test SET value = value + 3 WHERE id = 1;
```

According to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxabCqWsFHg about MVCC (at 15'00), this update should be rejected. But MySQL accepted this update.

**Session B**

```
SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = 1;
  15
```

So this select gets an unexpected result: the commit from **Session A** is visible in **Session B**.

My MySQL version is 5.7.26, and the isolation level is REPEATABLE-READ.

**=== UPDATE ===**

This case works as expected for MariaDB 10.4.10 with RocksDB engine.

In **Session B**

```
UPDATE test SET value = value + 3 WHERE id = 1;
```

It returns

```
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (snapshot conflict)
```

Answer (score 2):

In InnoDB, locking statements don't obey the REPEATABLE-READ isolation.

Locks always affect the most recently committed version of the row. So they behave as if you had used READ-COMMITTED.

This affects `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, as well as locking reads such as `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`.

But once you do UPDATE a row, the new version becomes visible in your transaction.

Comment: Seems `REPEATABLE-READ` doesn't work for this "Repeatable Write" scenario. I changed the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` and work as expected: MVCC seems not enabled and rows locked.